# Text View font type & size in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i am using below code to change the the font type of text view. but its not changing the font

textView3.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17.0f];
tell me where i am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code is correct. If that is the code that you are using, you should check whether it is being called. Try putting an `NSLog("changing font");` call right before it or something, so you can tell whether or not it is really happening.

A few suggestions, though. There is probably a more descriptive name for your textview than textView3. Don't worry about your variable names being too verbose; believe me, it's a good thing. Also, if textView3 is an instance variable, you really shouldn't be accessing it directly. Use encapsulation by declaring it as a `@property` and then `@synthesize`-ing it. Then, your call might look like `self.textViewThatDoesSomething.font = …`.

Good luck!

**Update:** I just had another idea. It may be that your `textView3` is not hooked up properly in Interface Builder. Check that and try again.

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
textview.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:FontSize];
```

Where `FontSize` is an `int`.